# Android build failed on createing profile with gradlew

Tags: android

I'm trying to create profile for my andoird application with this command:

```
./gradlew assemleDebug --dry-run --configure-on-demand --daemon --profile
```

after run command i get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'CafeAlachiqPro'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta2/gradle-3.0.0-beta2.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta2/gradle-3.0.0-beta2.jar
     Required by:
         project :

BUILD FAILED in 7s
```

I'm using latest version of gradle and i set that on application gradle file as:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add new Google Maven repository to your `build.gradle` file:

```
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

Comment: i have that on `build.gradle`